# Media queries works fine when I resize my browser but not on mobile

Tags: html, css

I've been working on making a site responsive and I only tested it by resizing my browser but when I thought I was finished, I tested it on mobile and it's not working at all. This is some examples of my media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width:645px) {}

@media screen and (max-width:1366px) {}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {}

@media screen and (max-width:980px) {}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Can you post some examples that aren't working on mobile. Mobile devices don't behave differently than resizing browser windows, unless you use `x-device-width` queries.

Comment: https://volurus.netlify.app (here's the site) if you wanna test it out yourself, by not working I mean like nothing that I did is working its like I didn't do any work

Comment: On your site, your CSS is in the wrong order. You have a few `max-width` queries, but since CSS cascades and reads from top to bottom, your `max-width: 900` will always override your `500`. And if you are overriding elements below that, those will override your media queries...because top to bottom. This is a good example where you should develop for mobile-first and use `min-width` to scale up.

Comment: fixed that and i still have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `max-width` use `max-width & min-width`. This way it's gonna work finely.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1366px) and (min-width: 1024px) {}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 980px) {}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) and (min-width: 645px) {}

@media screen and (max-width: 645px) {} This is mobile first
```

Comment: The problem is your code then not the queries.